# render custom class with public static map variable in apex pageblock

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm having issues calling a class that works fine in Lightning Component within a visualforce page using apex

i tried this but getting the error unknown property httpCallOutCtrl.getCalloutResponseContents

```
    <apex:pageBlock title="Visualforce (Using standard Visualforce Components)" mode="detail">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!getCalloutResponseContents}" var="sf">
                    <apex:column headerValue="postId" value="{!sf.val}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="ID" value="{!sf.id}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!sf.name}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="email" value="{!sf.email}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="body" value="{!sf.body}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

heres my class

```
public class httpCallOutCtrl {
    @AuraEnabled


    public static Map < String, Object > getCalloutResponseContents(ID contactId) {
        String baseURL = 'some-site.com';
        String apiKey = 'some-key';

        Contact contact = [SELECT external_id__c FROM Contact WHERE Id=:contactId];
        string AdvanceId = Contact.external_id__c
        String url = baseURL + AdvanceId +'/?api_key='+apiKey ;

        // Instantiate a new http object
        Http h = new Http();

        // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');

        // Send the request, and return a response
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        System.debug('response:--> ' + res.getBody());

        // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
        Map < String,
        Object > resultsMap = (Map < String, Object > ) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
        system.debug('resultsMap-->' + resultsMap);
        return resultsMap;

    }

}
```

Comment: I guess people are making too many assumptions... What does the response actually look like? Is it really a map? If so, you need to rework some of your code.

Comment: @sfdcfox if i console.log my response in the lightning controller , it is an object array of objects that i then can iterate over in lightning...I suppose the best way to put this is i need a class that I can use for lightning and apex because our org will support both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualforce is trying to find an attribute `getCalloutResponseContents` which you have used in `<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!getCalloutResponseContents}" var="sf">`

Moreover, the value of `<apex:pageBlocktable>` will be of type `List`, not `Map`.

Secondly, you are referencing the method `getCalloutResponseContents(ID contactId)` which expects parameter as contactId, which is also not matching.

I would suggest this approach.

1. Create a class which will hold those attributes which you are trying to show in VFP.

**MyValueObject**

```
public class MyValueObject {
  public Integer id;
  public String name;
  public String email;
  public String body;
 }
```

2. Create `myValueObjectResult` class

**myValueObjectResult**

```
public class myValueObjectResult {
  public myValueObject myValueObj;
}
```

3. Create a property in the controller

**property**

```
List<myValueObjectResult> lstmyValueObjectResult {get;set;}
```

4. from httpResponse prepare the result

**change your controller method**

```
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
result = (myValueObjectResult) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), MyValueObject.class);
lstmyValueObjectResult.add(result);
```

5. Finally try to show the result in VFP

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Visualforce (Using standard Visualforce Components)" mode="detail">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstmyValueObjectResult}" var="sf">
        <apex:column headerValue="postId" value="{!sf.val}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="ID" value="{!sf.id}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!sf.name}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="email" value="{!sf.email}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="body" value="{!sf.body}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

You can refer this answer for this approach.[Create an Apex class that calls a REST endpoint and write a test class - Trailhead](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171161/create-an-apex-class-that-calls-a-rest-endpoint-and-write-a-test-class-trailhe/171164#171164)

Comment: Can you even pass arguments to a getter method/ construct a getter with parameter ?

Comment: I am writing, actually he is doing wrong

Comment: @SantanuBoral thank you for the example, the quick question is then after I make these changes, will i be able to call the class in my lightning controller without any issue? I'm trying to make a single class work for both apex(classic ) and lightning

Comment: @JayRizzi Yes, his latest edits basically describe what I would have, but in more detail. Go with this solution, it should work fine.

Comment: Ok, i am attempting today and will let you know how it goes, thanks so far everyone